# Norton Security and Steam

Tags: steam, technical-issues

For the past few days steam has refused to log me in. It would either A: say there is a connection issue and make me want to "retry connection" or after i log in just freeze. I decided to check the steam support troubleshoot page and it suggested that if i get Norton anti-virus to not interfere it may run.

Could someone run me through the steps of how to fix it?

Comment: You...want us to help you fix Norton?

Comment: i was asking if there were steps to how to allow steam to run without Norton interfering possibly

Comment: Here are a few links that may be relevant to your case: **1.** http://community.norton.com/en/forums/norton-360-and-steam **2.** https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9828-SFLZ-9289 **3.** http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2813067

Comment: You should first check to see if it's Norton interfereing.  Disable it entirely, and run Steam.  If it still doesn't work, you know it's not Norton.

Comment: Norton must have a "Disable Antivirus" option, clicking on the icon in the system tray should show something like that.

Comment: ok ill see if this fixes it

Comment: disabling everything didnt help so it may not be the firewall

Comment: Yeah.... I don't think we can do anything else with the information you have provided...

Comment: thats fine. i think its safe to say that it isnt norton. Thank you anyway

Comment: If it really comes down to it, you could re-install steam (but that is only for a last resort)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about configuring Norton's firewall, which is not a gaming-specific task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got on Skype with DavWhodums and was able to find an answer (we know each in real life).

First, you load up the Norton Internet Security HUB. Then, go to the advanced settings. Once there, you go to the tab under Network Protection, and turn off Smart Firewall. Once done, Steam will work.

Note: For your own computer's safety, you should re-enable it when ever you are browsing the web outside of Steam, as it will leave some of your computer unprotected.

Comment: Disabling the firewall entirely sounds like a rather unsafe thing to do.  I don't think that's a solution we should be promoting for anything but troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: @Frank Some antivirus are really stubborn when allowing or disallowing stuff. The best thing to do would be to add an exception, but with Norton being the pain it is, I doubt it's possible.

Comment: @Zerjack While I agree that Norton can be a pain, it's still better than disabling your firewall entirely.  If Norton can't do it, the answer is to find a better firewall product, not just turn it off.

Comment: @Frank I had told him to try and use/get a different one, but his parents would not allow him to do it, and seeing that his computer is a family one, he could not easily change it without getting in trouble.

Comment: @ShadowZ. The correct answer, then, is to open an exception in the firewall for Steam.  Going without a firewall is just asking for something bad to happen.  Note: It's the virus scanner that usually stops the exploits that come through browsing, not the firewall.  That's for all the OTHER things that try to get in.